# I keep getting 415 error while post json data to asp.net controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to develop simple jouneral voucher form.

```
var Things=[];
    function addNewEntry() {
            var thing =  {
            //Id: parseInt($('#Id').val()),
            AcNumber: $('#AcNumber').val(),
            TranAmount: parseInt($('#TranAmount').val()),
            TranType: $('#TranType').val(),
            Tdate: $('#Tdate').val(),

        };
            things.push(thing);
            return things;

        }

function clickPostBtn() {
            $('#post').click(function (ev) {
                console.log('post botton work started');
                ev.preventDefault();
                addNewEntry();
                //debit credit validation
                var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(things);
                $.ajax({
                        contentType: 'application/Json; charset=UTF-8',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'POST',
                         url: '/Transaction/DoubleEntry',
                         data: myJsonString,
                        success: function () {
                            alert('success');
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            $('#result').html(response);
                        }

                    });
                    document.getElementById('myform').submit();
```

my controller looks like below

```
        public IActionResult doubleentry([FromBody] IEnumerable<TransactionTbl> trans)
    {
       //do something with incoming data

        return RedirectToAction("dummyview", "Transaction");
    }
```

whenever i click post button, data do get my controller but throw 415 after that,
i have tried with in ajax
application/x-www.formencoded
multipart/formdata

with and without binding attribute in controller.

Comment: what content type is the server *expecting*? - you're sending json

Comment: Can you try with content type `application/json` (notice everything is in lowercase)  without the charset ?

Comment: @JaromandaX how to figure out what content type is server expecting.

Comment: @Hrishi tried, still same result, thanks

Comment: did you write the server code? if so, what did you write it to expect?

Comment: @JaromandaX i have left it to default, and that is causing error, i used form tag helper to send the form to my designated action that cater the request and that helps,